# How do I add a picture to the richTextBox without using Copy/Paste

Tags: c#, image, richtextbox

How to can adds a picture to the `richTextBox` without using Copy/Paste?

Comment: without using Copy/Paste? :|

Comment: @MThreat Suggested duplicate have options without using copy/paste. Check that

Comment: Did not find anything

Comment: which RichTextBox? Winforms or WPF? This is game changing detail, you should always mention the class library instead of your favorite programming language which does not help at all in solving your problem.

Comment: oh i'm sorry , I mean was winform